# How to convert this Xceed XAML to C#

Tags: c#, xaml, xceed

I am trying to dynamically build columns in C#, but I am not sure how to convert this to C#

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="Name" 
             Title="Name"
             DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"
             CellContentTemplate="{StaticResource InputManagerNameCellTemplate}"
             AllowAutoFilter="False"/>
```

I know how to convert all of that BUT the DisplayMemberBinding part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Binding()
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty),
    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self)
}
```

Empty Binding in XAML is a shortcut to bind to DataContext on the same element.